# Write a Prolog predicate next(X,List,List1)

Tags: prolog

Prolog predicate `next(X, List,List1)`, that returns in `List1` the next element(s) from List that follows `X`, e.g., `next(a,[a,b,c,a,d],List1)`, will return `List1=[b,d]`.

I have tried following:

```
next(X, [X,Y|List], [Y|List1]) :-   % X is the head of the list
    next(X, [Y|List], List1).
next(X, [Y|List], List1) :-         % X is not the head of the list
    X \== Y,
    next(X, List, List1).
next(_,[], []).
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't comply with item 3 of [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I don't see an attempt and a specific question here.

Comment: What results are you seeing that you don't expect? Did you try doing a `trace`?

Comment: one liner: `next(X,List,List1) :- findall(Y,(nth1(I,List,X),succ(I,J),nth1(J,List,Y)),List1).`

Answer (score 1):

First, whenever possible, use [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) for expressing term inequality!

Second, the question you asked is vague about corner cases: In particular, it is not clear how `next(E,Xs,Ys)` should behave if there are multiple neighboring `E`s in `Xs` or if `Xs` ends with `E`.

That being said, here's my shot at your problem:

```
next(E,Xs,Ys) :-
   list_item_nexts(Xs,E,Ys).

list_item_nexts([],_,[]).
list_item_nexts([E],E,[]).
list_item_nexts([I|Xs],E,Ys) :-
   dif(E,I),
   list_item_nexts(Xs,E,Ys).
list_item_nexts([E,X|Xs],E,[X|Ys]) :-
   list_item_nexts(Xs,E,Ys).
```

Let's see some queries!

```
?- next(a,[a,b,c,a,d],List1).
List1 = [b,d] ;
false.

?- next(a,[a,a,b,c,a,d],List1).
List1 = [a,d] ;
false.

?- next(a,[a,a,b,c,a,d,a],List1).
List1 = [a,d] ;
false.
```

Note that above queries succeed, but leave behind useless choicepoints.
This inefficiency can be dealt with, but I suggest figuring out more complete specs first:)

Comment: Isn't there a more deterministic version? Without the leftover choicepoints?

Answer (score 1):

This version is deterministic for the cases given by @repeat using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868) and `(=)/3`. It shows how purity and efficiency can coexist in one and the same Prolog program.

```
next(E, Xs, Ys) :-
   xs_e_(Xs, E, Ys).

xs_e_([], _E, []).
xs_e_([X|Xs], E, Ys) :-
   if_(X = E, xs_e_xys(Xs, E, Ys), xs_e_(Xs, E, Ys)).

xs_e_xys([], _E, []).
xs_e_xys([X|Xs], E, [X|Ys]) :-
   xs_e_(Xs, E, Ys).
%xs_e_xys([X|Xs], E, [X|Ys]) :- % alternate interpretation
%   xs_e_([X|Xs], E, Ys).
```